# Добавление класса, когда скролл доходит до низа документа -50px

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть класс, к примеру,

```
.development {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Нужно, чтобы когда я скролю вниз страницы, и до самого низа остается, к примеру, 50px, добавился какой-то класс, например:

```
.development-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Как найти блок, отсчитывая от верха, или сделать, чтобы класс добавлялся при скролле до определенного блока известно, но это не то. Нужно именно, чтобы при скролле до -..px до низа всего документа.

Заранее спасибо!!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так

```js
document.onscroll = () => {
  const scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight; // вся возможная высота прокрутки
  const scrollY = window.scrollY; // текущее значение прокрутки
  const clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight; // высота видимой части экрана
  if (scrollHeight - (scrollY + clientHeight) > 50) {
    if(document.body.classList.contains('active')) {
      document.body.classList.remove('active');
    }
  } else {
    if(!document.body.classList.contains('active')) {
      document.body.classList.add('active');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

body.active {
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Тот же самый код, что у ThisMan, но с учётом производительности и без лишних сравнений.

```js
document.onscroll = () => {
  const scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
  const scrollY = window.scrollY;
  const clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  const list = document.body.classList;
  if (scrollHeight - (scrollY + clientHeight) > 50)
    list.remove('active')
  else list.add('active');
}
```

Comment: А в чем именно производительность? Какая операция затратней: поиск или удаление?

Comment: Более меньшее взаимодействие с дом объектом и без пустый проверок на отсутствие класса. Вместо этого можно было просто запустить один раз код, который удалаяет класс, а не дважды делать то, что совсем не нужно.

Comment: > _просто запустить один раз код, который удалаяет класс_
у вас при каждом скролле, если расстояние больше 50, будет вызываться `list.remove('active')`, и вопрос что быстрее проверка или удаление (пусть уже и не существующего класса, но подразумевает ли это ту же проверку под капотом?)

Comment: > _Более меньшее взаимодействие с дом объектом_
то что вы сохранили ссылку в переменную дает профит? Тут ведь обращение к св-ву, которое не вызывает даже рефлоу или репейнт